# Python requests module GET method: handling pagination token in params containing %

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to handle an API response with pagination. The first page provides a pagination token to reach the next one, but when I try to feed this back into the `params` parameter of the `requests.get` method it seems to slightly encode the token in the wrong way.

My attempt to retrieve the next page (using the `response` output of the first `requests.get` method):

```
# Initial request
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=params)

params.update({"paginationToken": response.json()["paginationToken"]})

# Next page
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=params)
```

This fails with status 500: Internal Server Error and message `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.`

An example pagination token:
`gyuqfh%2bqyNrV9SI1%2bXulE6MXxJgb1VmOu68eH4YZ6dWUgRItb7yJPnO9bcEXdwg6gnYStBuiFhuMxILSB2gpZCLb2UjRE0pp9RkDdIP226M%3d`

The `url` attribute of `response` seems to show a slightly different token if you look carefully, especially around the '%' signs:
`https://www.wikiart.org/en/Api/2/DictionariesByGroup?group=1&paginationToken=gyuqfh%252bqyNrV9SI1%252bXulE6MXxJgb1VmOu68eH4YZ6dWUgRItb7yJPnO9bcEXdwg6gnYStBuiFhuMxILSB2gpZCLb2UjRE0pp9RkDdIP226M%253d`

For example, the pagination token and url end differently: `226M%3d` and `226M%253d`. When I manually copy the first part of the url and add in the correct pagination token it does retrieve the information in a browser.

Am I missing some kind of encoding I should apply to the `request.get` parameters before feeding them back into a new request?

Comment: Was there a final solution to this as I've got the same problem. Thx

Comment: My issue was solved by using the answer of Dan-Dev below, I simply had to use the unquote function on the pagination token before sending it back in the `params` dictionary of the next GET request.

Comment: Thanks. I did the same and it worked too. I need to look at the request sessions object to see if it provides better fail-safe connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right it is some form of encoding, percentage encoding to be precise. It is frequently used to encode URLs. It is easy to decode:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

pagination_token="gyuqfh%252bqyNrV9SI1%252bXulE6MXxJgb1VmOu68eH4YZ6dWUgRItb7yJPnO9bcEXdwg6gnYStBuiFhuMxILSB2gpZCLb2UjRE0pp9RkDdIP226M%253d"
pagination_token = unquote(pagination_token)
print(pagination_token)
```

Outputs:

```
gyuqfh%2bqyNrV9SI1%2bXulE6MXxJgb1VmOu68eH4YZ6dWUgRItb7yJPnO9bcEXdwg6gnYStBuiFhuMxILSB2gpZCLb2UjRE0pp9RkDdIP226M%3d
```

But I expect that is half your problem, use a requests session object https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects to make the requests as there is most likely a cookie which will be sent with the request to be used in conjunction with the pagination token. I can not tell for sure as the website is currently down.